# How to make react select an params on axios?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios, react-select

I am newbie on ReactJs, I  have a table Product on MySQL and  I developed a dynamic table on ReactJS on the frontEnd using MySQL and NodeJs on Backend, my dynamic table has four columns : Product, Quantity, Price and total, I want when I select a product on the Product column, this Price will be displayed on its column.

My router is :

```
exports.getPrixprod = function(req,res) {

    connection.query('SELECT PrixV FROM produits where Nomp = ?', [req.params.Nomp], function(error, results, fields) {
        if (error) throw error;
        res.send(JSON.stringify(results));
        console.log(results);
    });
}
```

My class is :

```
class AjouterFacture extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

      Produits: [],
      Quantite: "",
      Prix: "",
      lineItemData: [],
       selectprdt: props.match.params.selectprdt,
      id: 0
    };
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleRowDelete = this.handleRowDelete.bind(this);
    this.handleRowAdd = this.handleRowAdd.bind(this);
    this.getTotal = this.getTotal.bind(this);
    this.DatefactChanged = this.DatefactChanged.bind(this);
    this.handleQuantiteChange = this.handleQuantiteChange.bind(this);
    this.handleselectprdtChange = this.handleselectprdtChange.bind(this);

  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    console.log("nextProps", nextProps);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    axios({
      method: "get",
      url: "/app/getNomprod/",
      withCredentials: true,
    }).then(response => {
      if (response && response.data) {
        this.setState({
          Produits: response.data
        });
      }
    }).catch(error => console.log(error));

  }
  popupAjout(event) {
    const getAlert = () => (<SweetAlert 
       success 
       title="Ajout facture"
     onConfirm={ this.handleSubmit}
        >
   UNe facture  est ajoutée avec succés 
      </SweetAlert>);
    this.setState({
      alert: getAlert()
    });
  }
  handleSubmit() {

    var lp = {
      Nomp: this.state.selectprdt,
      QuantiteF: this.state.QuantiteF,
    }
    axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: '/app/ajouterlp/',
      data: lp,
      withCredentials: true,
      headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      }
    }).then(function(response) {
      this.setState({
        alert: null
      });
      this.props.history.push('/factures/listefactures')
    }.bind(this))


  handleQuantiteChange(index, value) {
    const rowDataCopy = this.state.rowData.slice(0);
    rowDataCopy[index] = Object.assign({}, rowDataCopy[index], {
      Quantite: parseInt(value, 10)
    });
    this.setState({
      rowData: rowDataCopy
    });
  }
  handleselectprdtChange(index, value) {
    const rowDataCopy = this.state.rowData.slice(0);
    rowDataCopy[index] = Object.assign({}, rowDataCopy[index], {
      selectprdt: value

    });

     axios({
      method: "get",
      url: "/app/getPrixprod/" + this.props.match.params.selectprdt,
      withCredentials: true,
    }).then(response => {
      if (response && response.data) {
        this.setState({
          Prix: response.data

        });
    }; console.log(response.data);


    }).catch(error => console.log(error));
    this.setState({
      rowData: rowDataCopy
    });


  }

  render() {

    let {
      Clients
    } = this.state.Clients;
    var Cd = {
      pointerEvents: 'none'
    }
    let {
      Produits
    } = this.state.Produits;
    let {
      rowData
    } = this.state.rowData;
    const Prix = this.state;
    return (<div className="animated fadeIn">




 <h6>  <Label ><strong>Veuillez ajouter au moins un produit :  </strong></Label></h6>
        <Table responsive style={items} >
        <thead style={back}>
                  <tr>
                    <th>PRODUIT</th>
                    <th>QUANTITE</th>
                    <th>PRIX UNITAIRE</th>
                    <th>TOTAL</th>
                    <th></th>
                  </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                {this.state.rowData.map((data, index) => (
              <tr key={index} id={index}>
                <td>
                  {" "}  <Input type="select" name="selectedcl" id="selectcl"
                          placeholder="Veuillez sélectionner un produit"  value={data.selectprdt}
                    onChange={(e) => this.handleselectprdtChange(index, e.target.value)} >
           <option  key={-1} hidden>Choisisr un produit</option>


                     {  this.state.Produits.map((pdt, i) => 
                     <option key={i}  value="select">{pdt.Nomp}</option>
                     )} 


                      </Input>
                    </td>
                    <td><Input type="number" 
                          value={data.Quantite || 0} onChange={(e) => this.handleQuantiteChange(index, e.target.value)}/></td>
                    <td>



                        <p>{ this.state.Prix} DT</p>


                        </td>
                <td  > 



                     <p key={index} className='pa2 mr2 f6'>{(data.Quantite || 0) * (Prix )}  DT</p>



                    </td>
                    <td>
                     <Button onClick={(e) => this.handleRowDelete(index)} active style={center}  size="sm" color="danger" className="btn-pill" aria-pressed="true">Effacer</Button>
      </td>{" "}
              </tr>
            ))}



                  <tr>

            <td/>
            <td/>
            <td/>
            <td/>
            <td><Button onClick={this.handleRowAdd} active style={center}  size="sm" color="info" className="btn-pill" aria-pressed="true">Ajouter une ligne</Button></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>

        <tfoot>
          <tr>

            <th></th>
            <th >Grand total :</th>
            <th>{this.getTotal()} DT</th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
</tfoot>

        </Table>




        </div>);
  }
  getTotal() {
    let grandTotal = 0;
    const rowTotals = this.state.rowData.map(row => (row.Quantite * row.PrixV) || 0);
    if (rowTotals.length > 0) {
      grandTotal = rowTotals.reduce((acc, val) => acc + val);
    }
    return grandTotal;
  }
  handleRowDelete(row) {
    const rowDataCopy = this.state.rowData.slice(0);
    rowDataCopy.splice(row, 1);
    this.setState({
      rowData: rowDataCopy
    });
  }
  handleRowAdd() {
    let id = this.state.id;
    id = id++;
    const rowDataCopy = this.state.rowData.slice(0);
    rowDataCopy.push({
      selectprdt: "",
      Quantite: 0,
      Prix: 0
    });
    this.setState({
      rowData: rowDataCopy,
      id: id
    });
  }
}
export default AjouterFacture;
```

When I run my backend with Postman, it works well, but when I run my Frontend, I get the Price `[]` on the console and I get the value of select `undefined` on the Network console :

[image]

How can I fix that please ?

Comment: Do your server and your frontend app live on the same address? I.e. do they both live on localhost:3000, or is one 3000 and another 3001?

Comment: The backend is on 4000 and the frontend is on 5000

Comment: Are you using create-react-app, and if so did you tell it where your backend is? If not, you may have to change `/app/ajouterlp/` to `localhost:4000/app/ajouterlp/`

Comment: @bwalshy I get the same issue. Can you take a look at the post ? I add the Network console result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For referencing `this.props.match.params` you need to use `react-router`. In case you are already using this library, then you need to wrap the component with `withRouter` HOC:

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';
class AjouterFacture extends Component {
...
}

export default withRouter(AjouterFacture);
```

Then you can get `this.props.match.params.selectprdt`. But do not forget to include this attribute in your react-router path somewhere in router component in a way like this:

```
<Route path='/facture/:selectprdt' component={AjouterFacture}>
```

And try not to use(it should not work by the way):

```
let {
  Clients
} = this.state.Clients;
let {
  Produits
} = this.state.Produits;
let {
  rowData
} = this.state.rowData;
```

and use these instead:

```
const {
  Clients, Produits, rowData
} = this.state;
```

You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring)

Comment: Thank you @Aleksandr for your explanations

Answer (score 1):

change:

`let {
      Produits
    } = this.state.Produits;`

for

`let {
      Produits
    } = this.state;`

Comment: I change it and it's still the same issue